# CSS Background Image center is not the same as margin:0 auto with scrollbars

Tags: html, css

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/7zb6P/1/

Both the yellow box and the background image are centered in the scrolling `div`, although their center is slightly different. This seems to be due to the background being centered to the whole area (including scrollbar), but the `div` being centered to the content area (not including scrollbar) - see it centered correctly without the scrollbar http://jsfiddle.net/7zb6P/2/

Interestingly IE7 renders it "correctly", but IE8+ and other browsers render it as described above.

I have had a play around with background-origin (and -webkit-background-origin) but none of the properties seem to have any effect.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT: More information: The linked fiddle is just a minimal example of the problem, my actual problem is with whole sites where the  is centered (with `margin:0 auto`) and has a background image centered (using `background-position: center top`). The solution needs to work on a large number of sites of which I cannot change the HTML, so it needs to be a CSS based (or possibly Javascript based) solution. Thanks.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/leobeckons/7zb6P/3/

Comment: Thanks Max, sadly that does not solve the problem. As the fiddle I linked is just a demo, the real problem is on the body element when it is centered with a background image aswell. I am not able to modify the HTML of the site (so to put a wrapper in or anything), so this solution must be in CSS alone (or possibly Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides with your background image. You're trying to center an image that (for CSS's purposes) has no center.

The image is 321 pixels wide. Which means the center of the image is 161.5 pixels. As the browser is unable to render that position it gets a 1 pixel offset.

Comment: Hello, while this is true, it is not the underlying problem. The background image is off by a lot more than 1px, it is off by about 10px.

Comment: Ah.. ok. I didn't notice. Sorry about that.